# How to construct $\delta^i$ morphism for right derived functors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Suppose $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is a left-exact functor between abelian categories. Assume $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives. I want to prove the following:

> For every short exact sequence $0 \to A \to A^\prime \to A^{\prime\prime} \to 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$, there exists a morphism $\delta^i : R^iF(A^{\prime\prime}) \to R^{i+1}F(A)$ for each $i \geq 0$ such that the sequence $0 \to R^0F(A) \to R^0F(A^\prime) \to R^0F(A^{\prime\prime}) \xrightarrow{\delta^0} R^1F(A) \to \cdots$ is exact.

Do I have to construct $\delta^i$ using the definition of right derived functors? If so, how can I? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your background and where have you looked for this result? I'd expect this to be in standard homological algebra references like Weibel - is the treatment there either not present or not to your liking?

Comment: I haven't taken homological algebra yet, this is a theorem in Hartshorne so I was expecting some kind of explanation in the book but found none. I think I should look up Weibel. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Hartshorne doesn't really explain much about homological algebra - if you haven't seen any of it before, I could see it being easy to be curious about more. I learned a lot out of Weibel when I was first picking it up and can recommend the book. You're welcome :)

Comment: This is in most standard homological algebra textbooks. It follows from the *Horshoe Lemma* and the long exact sequence coming from a short exact sequence of complexes. Perhaps this helps finding the reference.

Comment: @KReiser @ Pedro Thanks a lot :)